# What is wrong with this regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I have created one regular expression which is supposed to match for line starting with Project followed by either # or : or - followed by 1 to 3 digit number or simply Title.
For example, following lines should get matched

Project # 1

Project#1

Project :1

Project-123

Project Title

---

but following should not match

Project ABCD

Project*978

My Project

Projects handled

---

My regular expression is as follows :

```
^(\s)*?((Project( )*?(#|:|-| )( )*?(\d){1,3})|(PROJECT( )*?(#|:|-| )( )*?(\d){1,3})|Project Title|PROJECT TITLE)\b
```

Project keyword should be at the start of the line.

For some text, this regular expression is working fine.
But this regular expression is matching following line :

> Projects Handled:

I have no clue why it is happening.
Can anyone find out what is wrong with my regular expression?

I am using C# to do this.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I like to use a little tool called Expresso. It's good for building, playing with and debugging regular expressions: http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Comment: Kinda weird, I tried the exact pattern in C#, didn't match `Projects Handled:`

Comment: @Tom, I tried the same regex in expresso. In expresso it is not matching 'Projects Handled' but in C# its matching the same string that is 'Projects Handled'

Answer (score 1):

How about like this pattern?

```
@"Project\s*[#: -]\s*(?:\d+|[A-Z][a-z]+)"
```

Its does not match to

> Project ABCD
>
> Project*978
>
> My Project
>
> Projects handled

But will match to following patterns

```
Project # 1

Project#1

Project :1

Project-123

Project Title
```

There is a confusion part in **Project Title** and **Project ABCD** though. 
I assumed you only want title case.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Regex project = new Regex(@"^\s*?(?:Project *[#:\- ] *(\d){1,3}|Project Title)",
    RegexOptions.ECMAScript | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^\s*Project\s*([\-#:]\s*\d{1,3}|Title)\b
```

This allows optional spaces before and after `Project` and between `-#:` and the three digit number